# python syntax in read line file

Tags: python

I starting learn python ,but i meet a SyntaxError. when i build filter to get recent record in log file.
log file like this

```
  Sat Jun  2 03:32:13 2012 [pid 12461] CONNECT: Client "66.249.68.236"
  Sat Jun  2 03:32:13 2012 [pid 12460] [ftp] OK LOGIN: Client "66.249.68.236", anon     password "gxxglxxxxt@google.com"
  Sat Jun  2 03:32:14 2012 [pid 12462] [ftp] OK DOWNLOAD: Client "66.249.68.236",   "/pub/10.5524/100001_101000/100022/readme.txt", 451 bytes, 1.39Kbyte/sec


import time
lines=[]
f= open("/opt/CLiMB/Storage1/log/vsftp.log")
line = f.readline()
lines=[line for line in f]
def OnlyRecent(line):
    return time.strptime(line.split("[")[0].strip(),"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y" <(time.time()-(60*60*24*5)))
print ("\n".join(filter(OnlyRecent,lines)))
f.close()
```

error when run it

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "ex2.py", line 8, in ?
 print("\n".join(filter(OnlyRecent,lines)))
 File "ex2.py", line 7, in OnlyRecent
 return time.strptime(line.split("[")[0].strip(),"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y" <(time.time()-(60*60*24*5)))
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/_strptime.py", line 287, in strptime
 format_regex = time_re.compile(format)
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/_strptime.py", line 264, in compile
 return re_compile(self.pattern(format), IGNORECASE)
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/_strptime.py", line 251, in pattern
 format = regex_chars.sub(r"\\\1", format)
 TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

How to solve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous answers are correct, but there's another syntax error since you're using python version 3.x+, in which `print` is always called as a function.

So add that extra paren, then, make your `print` call a function call.

```
print("\n".join(filter(OnlyRecent,lines)))
```

P.S. It's also a good idea to use variables instead of cramming a lot of work onto one line
to make your code more readable.

Comment: thanks, when i change it, it has new error. i have already edit question.

Comment: @JesseSiu: The extra parenthesis was added in the wrong place.  You need to add it after the format string, i.e. `time.strptime(line.split("[")[0].strip(),"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y") < (time.time()-(60*60*24*5))`.  The error message is caused because you're passing the result of comparing a string to a float, which is a bool, as the second argument to `strptime` right now.  Also, since it looks like you're using Python 2.4, adding the parentheses around  `print` shouldn't have changed anything, so something you've said can't be right.

Comment: @DSM:Thanks, can you give me more detail, how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

On this line `return time.strptime(line.split("[")[0].strip(),"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y" <(time.time()-(60*60*24*5))` you have one missing closing parenthesis ')'.

Answer (score 0):

You need an extra close paranthesis at the end of return statement.

```
>>> def OnlyRecent(line):
...     return time.strptime(line.split("[")[0].strip(),"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y"   <(time.time()-(60*60*24*5)))
```

You could have found this from your console itself!

Comment: after i add a ')', it still has same problem

Comment: This isn't right.  It'll fix the SyntaxError the unbalanced parenthesis might cause, but it introduces a TypeError, because `strptime` should only get two arguments, and the second argument should be the format, not the result of a `str` to `float` comparison.

Comment: The question above is not constructive. we are not here to solve syntax errors. thats my point. the code above needs more cleaning

Answer (score 0):

Make your code easier to read by keeping lines short:

```
import time

def is_recent(line):
    time_string = line.split("[")[0].strip()
    line_time = time.strptime(time_string, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')

    return line_time < (time.time() - (60 * 60 * 24 * 5))

with open('/opt/CLiMB/Storage1/log/vsftp.log', 'r') as handle:
    lines = filter(is_recent, handle)

print '\n'.join(lines)
```